# Uncaught Error Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /path/to/chromium ENOENT

Tags: puppeteer

So my problem is that I can't run puppeteer headlessly and I've done many things to try and fix it and I've tried going in to the link and I've tried to solve it myself and I just can't do it myself. I've just recently started coding and I'm been on this problem for weeks so if someone would be able to help me would it be amazing.

This is my code:

```
async function startBrowser() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/path/to/chromium', headless: true, 
ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
return page;
}


const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker')
puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }))
const product_url = "https://www.zalando.se/nike-sportswear-air-flight-lite-mid-hoega- 
sneakers-whiteblack-ni112n02z-a11.html"
const cart = "https://www.zalando.se/cart"




async function addToCart(page){
// going to website
await page.goto(product_url)
// clicking "handla"
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- Vn-7c- FCIprz 
heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF  
PLvOOB']");
await page.click("button[class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 
LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF  PLvOOB']", elem 
=> elem.click);
// clicking "OK" to cookies
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='uc-btn uc-btn-primary']");
await page.click("button[class='uc-btn uc-btn-primary']");
// clicking "size EU 41"
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('_6G4BGa _0Qm8W1 _7Cm1F9 FxZV-M 
IvnZ13 Pb4Ja8 ibou8b JT3_zV ZkIJC- Md_Vex JCuRr_ na6fBM _0xLoFW FCIprz pVrzNP KRmOLG NuVH8Q') 
[4].click());
console.log("körs")
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// going to "cart"
await page.goto(cart)
// clicking "gå till checkout"
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='z-1-button z-coast-base-primary-accessible z-coast- 
base__sticky-sumary__cart__button-checkout z-1-button--primary z-1-button--button']");
await page.click("button[class='z-1-button z-coast-base-primary-accessible z-coast- 
base__sticky-sumary__cart__button-checkout z-1-button--primary z-1-button--button']", elem => 
elem.click);
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// logging into gmail
const email = await page.waitForSelector("[id='login.email']");
await email.type('marc.ehadsadwa@gmail.com');
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
// typing in password
const password = await page.waitForSelector("[id='login.secret']");
await password.type('Bradasdwad');
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// clicking "log in"
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- 
Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv 
r9BRio mo6ZnF E6Km4r')[0].click());
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// clicking "hämta hos postombud"
}



async function checkout(){
var page = await startBrowser();
await addToCart(page);
}

checkout();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /path/to/chromium ENOENT


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
at onClose (undefined:299:20)
at <anonymous> (undefined:293:24)
at emit (undefined:513:28)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (undefined:289:12)
at onErrorNT (undefined:476:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (undefined:82:21)
```

Comment: I think `/path/to/chromium/` is a placeholder. Try putting your actual path to the chromium executable there.

Comment: I tried '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' and it didn't work. Is it not a path or did is there something else I can do?